# Why does SSH client offer public key to SSH server?

Tags: openssh

If I enable `-vvv` when logging in to a SSH server using key-based authentication, then according to debug messages SSH client offers public key to SSH server:

```
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 149
```

Why is that so? SSH server already has my public key in `authorized_keys` file. Or how to understand this `Offering public key`?

Answer (score 2):

The SSH server has your `public` key (from id_rsa.pub) in your authorized_keys. The ssh client has the `private` key (in id_rsa).

The debug message means the client is asking the server if it will accept authentication using that public/private keypair.